# create list of data frames from two lists of vectors via mapply

Tags: r

I expect a list of two data.frame instead of list of 4 vectors. what did i do wrong?

```
list1 <- list(1:3, 5:6)
list2 <- list(7:9, 10:11)
result <- mapply((function(x, y) data.frame(id = x, value = y)),
       list1, list2)
str(result)
# List of 4
# $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
# $ : int [1:3] 7 8 9
# $ : int [1:2] 5 6
# $ : int [1:2] 10 11
# - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : chr [1:2] "id" "value"
# ..$ : NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` in `mapply` to conserve the `list` structure

```
mapply(function(x, y) data.frame(id = x, value = y),
                    list1, list2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Or use `Map`

```
Map(function(x,y) data.frame(id=x, value=y), list1, list2)
```